# Insert a future date based on date when workflow runs?

Tags: slack

I want to set up a workflow where it runs every week, sends a message to certain people and has a variable date in it. Specific example below

> Happy Friday! Don't forget that the schedule for (Date 10 days in advance) is due today!

Is this something that is even possible to do on Slack?

I tried different coding/apps but I keep hitting dead ends. I want it to run in individual messages (since that's how we have the workflow set up currently) so is there is a Slack format like /date or similar that I can work with or around?